# Setting text to the UISearchBar when its firstresponder with controller change works weird

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar, settext, becomefirstresponder

In my app i have `UITextField` on view of VC1(`UIViewController`). When i change text in textfield i call pushing of another controller VC2 with `UISearchBar` on its view. After pushing im assigning `UISearchBar` text to the textfield text from VC1.

On xib my textfield already have some text "Test string".

When I'm append VC1 textfield with any char - VC2 pushing and text on searchbar is normal.

But when I'm press backspace key on iPhone keyboard - VC2 pushed and text on searchfield start deleting char by char, while whole string not been empted. It happend because delegate method calls recursively.

How to fix that behaviour of `UISearchBar`? I mush to have searchbar active with keyboard opened when VC2 appears! It's main condition. Sure, if i'll remove `[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]` all will works fine.

Some code here:

```
@implementation ViewController1

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString * resultString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
ViewController2 * vc2 = [ViewController2 new];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
[vc2 loadText: resultString];
return NO;
}

@end


@implementation ViewController2

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void) loadText: (NSString *) text
{
    self.searchBar.text = text;
}

@end
```

Sample source code of the problem: http://yadi.sk/d/NJmTLot73_vrE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through the code and for some reason the delete/backspace key is getting called repeatedly by the UIKeyboard's Accessibility function.  I haven't been able to find a reason yet but one workaround is to put the `[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];` line into `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear` - is that an acceptable workaround? The keyboard animation is slightly different but I'm not sure how sensitive your needs are to that.

Comment: Yeah! I have found this solution too. Also I have added `[textfield resignFirstReponser]` into shouldChangeCharactersInRange method of VC1, because keyboard move weird to new controller view from previous.
I think it solves problem, but not explain why iOS work so strange here. Hope Apple will fix that in future. Thanks 4 help.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing strange UISearchBar animations on iOS 7. Solved the problem by putting my becomeFirstResponder call in viewDidAppear with a delay of 0.1.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.searchBar performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a recursive call in your code.

```
self.searchBar.text = text;
```

calls to

```
textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:
```

which in turn calls to

```
loadText:
```

What you can do is remove the delegate from the searchBar uitextfield, set the text and then return the delegate. Something like this:

```
- (void) loadText: (NSString *) text
{
    self.searchBar.delegate = nil;
    self.searchBar.text = text;
    self.searchBar.delegate = vc1;
}
```

Comment: You wrong, shouldChangeCharactersInRange implemented in VC1 only. Its not cycle what im was talking about.
Check source code to understand problem.